# Name for the tables at the edges of the ER-diagram

Tags: data-modeling

When modelling large systems with some class graph or entity relationship diagram, there are often nodes at the edges of the graph. These may serve to describe the values that some attribute can take, but do not reference any other classes/tables themselves.

An example: say we want to model the gender of a person using a database table. We can then add any number of genders to this table; this allows for a flexible system. This table does not reference any others, but is referenced by person.

Is there a general name for such a concept? It's like a value object, but even more limited (because it's used to describe only a single selectable label)

Answer (score 0):

They're commonly called lookup tables, or dimension tables in data warehouse terminology.  In relational terms, they would correspond to user-defined domains.